# Palette method using numpy

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, colors, video-processing

I am trying to apply the numpy palette method to an opencv processed video (references: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433604/opencv-setting-all-pixels-of-specific-bgr-value-to-another-bgr-value) and [this tutorial](http://opencvpython.blogspot.ch/2012/06/fast-array-manipulation-in-numpy.html) ). I aim at replacing all frame pixels of a certain color range by another. The code below is an example that replaces black with green. Unfotunately, my code raises an error on line:

```
image[np.where((image==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))]=green
```

the error: exceptions.ValueError:axis(=2) out of bounds

I am running python 2.7 with PyScripter, and I find it odd because the code did work before, and I did not make any major modification to it. Can someone please help me? I am quite stuck on this one...

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##IMPORTS
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
import time

##VARIABLES
#colors
green=[0,255,0]

##MAIN
#video file input
frames = raw_input('Please input video file:')
if not frames:
   print "This program requires a file as input!"
   sys.exit(1)

#create window
cv.NamedWindow("image", 1)

#File capture
vidFile = cv.CaptureFromFile(frames)
nFrames = int(  cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) )
fps = cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS )
waitPerFrameInMillisec = int( 1/fps * 1000/1 )

#time adjustment, frame capture
for f in xrange( nFrames ):
   frame = cv.QueryFrame( vidFile )

   # create the images we need
   image = cv.CreateImage (cv.GetSize (frame), 8, 3)

   # copy the frame, so we can draw on it
   if not frame:
       break
   else:
       cv.Copy (frame, image)

   #get pixel HSV colors
   rows,cols=cv.GetSize(frame)
   image=np.asarray(image)
   image[np.where((image==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))]=green
   image=cv.fromarray(image)

   #show the image
   cv.ShowImage("image", image)

   #quit command ESC
   if cv.WaitKey(waitPerFrameInMillisec)==27:
      break
   else:
      cv.WaitKey(waitPerFrameInMillisec) % 0x100
```

Comment: It would seem that your image has less than 3 dimensions. Add a `print image.shape` before the line raising the error. I'm not sure about cv, but I know that when converting images to numpy arrays with PIL, the return is a 1D array. You may need to replace the current line with `image=np.asarray(image).reshape(rows, cols, -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. In fact, the answer was not a modification of the line raising the exception, but rather on a modification of the arguments that were passed to this line. Indeed, it seems that the '[:,:]' arguments are required in opencv when converting cvMat to Numpy and back.
Here is the corrected code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##IMPORTS
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

##VARIABLES
#colors
green=[0,255,0]

##MAIN
#start video stream analysis
frames = raw_input('Please enter video file:')
if not frames:
   print "This program requires a file as input!"
   sys.exit(1)


# first, create the necessary windows
cv.NamedWindow ('image', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)


#File capture
vidFile = cv.CaptureFromFile(frames)
nFrames = int(  cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) )
fps = cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS )
waitPerFrameInMillisec = int( 1/fps * 1000/1 )


for f in xrange( nFrames ):
   #time adjustment, frame capture
   sec = f/fps
   frame = cv.QueryFrame( vidFile )

   # create the images we need
   image = cv.CreateImage (cv.GetSize (frame), 8, 3)


   # copy the frame, so we can draw on it
   if not frame:
      break
   else:
      cv.Copy (frame, image)

   #Replace pixel colors
   rows,cols=cv.GetSize(frame)
   image=np.asarray(image[:,:])
   image[np.where((image==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))]=green
   image=cv.fromarray(image[:,:])

   #show the image
   cv.ShowImage("image", image)

   #quit command ESC
   if cv.WaitKey(waitPerFrameInMillisec)==27:
      break
   else:
      cv.WaitKey(waitPerFrameInMillisec) % 0x100

cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```