# location of specific rgb pixel

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm struggling to find the (x,y) coordinate of certain RGB values in an image. Lets say I edit an image and put a single pixel of (0,255,5), how can I find the 2D coordinate?

My current approach is using `numpy.where`, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm aware of opencv storing images in BGR. I don't really want to use the HSV approach and `inRange` because I just want single pixels of very specific values, so that would be overkill.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    im = cv2.imread(image)
    point = np.where(im == 5,255,0))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `np.where(im == [0,255,5]))` ?

Comment: that does the same thing unfortunately

Comment: The approach is basically correct. You just need to use Python correctly(which is not really my thing :D). Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12138972/5008845)

Comment: yeah I know this is simple, ive used opencv a lot in python and c++ so this frustrates me to no end!

Comment: You say you are aware of BGR vs RGB but still you search for RGB? Why is that? I think you should search for `np.where(im == [5,255,0]))`

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong in question. that still returns way more values than it should so i dont think its working

Comment: Are you sure that there can be only one pixel with that exact value? Have you checked the results? Maybe there realy are more pixel with this bgr value?

Comment: And check out this question, it is about replacing pixels but includes finding them first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433604/opencv-setting-all-pixels-of-specific-bgr-value-to-another-bgr-value

Comment: i just checked for pink pixels and there is nothing even remotely pink, still returns a lot. ill check it out thanks

Comment: I think @Mailerdaimon is correct , your image must contain many pixels of same value.. You should check it first.  You can also use a  trick, convert your image to BGRA and the whole img will have same alpha value, you can change alpha value of pixel which you are editing, slightly. And then use np.where(im == (5,255,0,alpha_value))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the (x,y) indexes of specific (R,G,B) color values from images stored in NumPy ndarrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138339/finding-the-x-y-indexes-of-specific-r-g-b-color-values-from-images-stored-in)