# How to remove glare from a face opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to posterize an image using opencv. Here's the input[image]

I added the following script [that i found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072667/8994551) to get a posterize effect:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')

n = 2    # Number of levels of quantization

indices = np.arange(0,256)   # List of all colors 

divider = np.linspace(0,255,n+1)[1] # we get a divider

quantiz = np.int0(np.linspace(0,255,n)) # we get quantization colors

color_levels = np.clip(np.int0(indices/divider),0,n-1) # color levels 0,1,2..

palette = quantiz[color_levels] # Creating the palette

im2 = palette[im]  # Applying palette on image

im2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(im2) # Converting image back to uint8

cv2.imshow('im2',im2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the output I'm getting by setting `n=5` which is close to my desired output

[image]

However the glaring on the original image is affecting the final output( I need an output with a face having almost the same colour). How do I remove glaring from the original input