# How to improve color layer mask to have mid tones?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, alpha

I would like to improve the layer mask that I am creating in Python. Although my mask pretty much hits the targeted color, my main problem with it, is it is doing so in binary, the pixel is either pure white or pure black. I'm unable to extrapolate the intensity of the color. I want to achieve something like how Photoshop does it wherein there are mid-tones of grey on the mask.

[image]
[image]

Here is the current attempt:
import cv2

```
image = cv2.imread('grade_0.jpg')

lower = np.array([0,0,0])
upper = np.array([12,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV), lower, upper)  
mask = 255 - mask
# mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask) #inverting black and white
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

cv2.imshow("output", output)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]
[image]

Here are the plain images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `inRange()` won't be enough then. you'll have to define which colors are fully "in" the mask, which are fully "out", and how intermediate colors are mapped to alpha values. all of that can be done with plain numpy operations, or OpenCV operations doing the same as the numpy operations, except with more optimization.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz im sorry im having trouble understanding the "in" and "out" analogy. Can you please show of an example how it is done? which specific functions are needed to achieve the result desired?

Comment: your `inRange` now filter all `h > 12`, so `h>12 -> mask = 1`, `h<=12 -> mask = 0`. What @ChristophRackwitz says is doing something like `h>50 -> mask = 1`, `h<12 -> mask=0`, and `12<=h<=50` scales linearly between `0,1`, i.e. `(h-12)/(50-12)`. Adjust the upper bound `50` accordingly. Remember `hue` is circular, so `h=179` is very close to `h=0`.

Comment: to segment hues near 0, there are two common approaches. (1) select two ranges, 0 and up, and 359 (or 179) and down. (2) shift/rotate hues (add, modulo) so the range you want is away from this wrap-around.

Comment: just checking... do you expect/hope/want/... answers to replicate whatever feature of Photoshop you presented there? if yes, how closely? or do you expect a solution to your histology task, which is as yet unspecified?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Just the photoshop part, i need to have a mask that is relatively close to what photoshop generated. maybe aroung 75-85% similar to what photoshop can do. If by histology task you mean my other questions, please ignore them for now.

Comment: It'd be useful to see what your target is (aka, what the output of photoshop is). I don't know why you don't just create a new image (mask), which computes a distance from the target color (I'm guessing 12,255,255). Then it'd be a variable grayscale mask. And you can multiply onto the image like you're currently doing.

Comment: @gnodab my target mask is the same as on the first image (right portion). Apologies but my knowledge of how color works is very minimal so when you say `computes a distance from the target color`  i have no idea how to implement that. If you can show me a snippet of code that does what you say, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-do-you-create-a-color-layer-mask-that-have-mid-tones/16946

Comment: bounties are a double-edged sword, with the worse edge usually cutting first: bounties attract junk answers, hoping to be rewarded anyway because OP can't tell. feed pigeons, get more pigeons.

Comment: If I didn’t have a headache right now, I might work on an elaborate example of how to select positive and negative pixels, model each distribution (mixture of gaussians maybe), and then calculate a (dis)similarity/distance measure for some pixel’s color, relative to those distributions. -- ditching the MoG, and ditching any standard deviations, you’d have two colors. then you could just get the vector between them, throw up decision planes for each side, and then get nice linear values for anything between those planes.

Comment: no headache today. I might give it a try this evening.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thats great to hear ! Id love to see your approach :)

Comment: @DrakeJest **(1)** Don't do it in binary if... _"I want to achieve something like how Photoshop does it"_. Photoshop makes a **greyscale** image (256 shades of black to white) as an **alpha mask** for the layer. **(2)** What is the value(s) of **sampled colors** in your Photoshop images? In case to recreate your expected results

Comment: @VC.One , yes i understand it cant be done in binary. When i first asked the question i  did not even know that masks are binary in nature. I cannot remember the exact value used in that image, but if i do it again in photoshop , its :  HEX 7d5c4d, here is the [image](https://ibb.co/d5HHK0d)

Comment: @DrakeJest Thanks for the update I'll try your numbers when I get a chance. Also you say _"...Didn't know that masks are binary in nature"_ Okay. I think the problem (of code results) is from a confusion with **bit-masking** versus **pixel masking**. I noticed in the Answers section, everyone stopped using. My final advice is get to a stage where you can loop through the pixels to manually edit each one. For each pixel, check if it is in range then (a) If True, convert it to greyscale and write into related output pixel (b) or if False then skip it but write black in the output.

Comment: don't get hung up on terms. the question is clear enough to understand you want something like an alpha channel that more or less smoothly corresponds to the staining of the tissue. there's no need to focus on touching pixels in a loop, or on _binary_-anything

Answer (score 3):

Biiiiiig picture first. It's clickable and should be clicked. Let your eyes wander.

[image]

Pick your parameters:

- The stain color you're interested in. I assumed some type of dark red/brown.
- The distance function. I picked a gaussian. It's nice.
- The parameters of the distance function. I show a bunch of sigmas, and two particular ways to weigh the colors.

Common definitions and functions:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

target = (75, 105, 150) # BGR

subject = cv.imread(...)

distvecs = subject - np.float32(target)[None, None, :]
```

One flavor of weighting the color differences:

```py
distvecs *= (0.114, 0.587, 0.299) # blue weighted least, according to perception
distance = distvecs.sum(axis=2) # manhattan distance
```

Other flavor of weighting the color differences:

```py
# equal weight, euclidean distance
distance = np.linalg.norm(distvecs, axis=2)
```

You can come up with whatever you like. You could even mess around with color spaces. There are no rules.

Applying the gaussian to the distances:

```py
def gaussian(x, sigma):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x, 2) / (2 * np.power(sigma, 2)))

def max_normalize(x):
    return x / x.max()

scored = max_normalize(gaussian(distance, sigma))
```

And that's the "mask".

And here's another result with a different target color, BGR tuple `(68, 60, 100)`

[image]

And another, for `(121, 45, 87)`:

[image]

---

I'm surprised that everyone seems to do some kind of threshold, i.e. visible discontinuities.

There is some of that in my solution too, but only *where* the pictures contain high frequency components (strong gradients).

Comment: Hello ! I have waited for your answer, and it was worth the wait. I think the np.linalg method seems to be more accurate, manhattan seems to hit the bluish pixels more. So far the best solution, I like how it doesnt hit the blue pixels as much as the other solutions

Comment: the stain _might_ have a touch of blue (if it's turning violet = red+blue) but it looks more brownish (red+green) to me. you can penalize blue by giving it extra weight, rather than less weight.

Comment: Indeed i can see the effect by increasing blue's weight. What would be the conditions for increasing/decreasing the colors weight? is it really just if i see certain color appearing in the mask, ill increase its weight until i dont see it anymore?

Comment: that would work. weight is linear, so are the euclidean and manhattan distances, but the gaussian is non-linear, i.e. if you vary both a linear and a non-linear parameter, you might see more effects than just by varying one. for experimenting, I'd recommend placing some OpenCV trackbars in the window for any parameters you want to explore. the tight feedback loop (try something, see the effect) will quickly give you an intuition for the parameters you choose to vary. when I whipped this up, I just edited the code and reran it, which makes changing of parameters very slow/coarse.

Comment: as for the "range and fuzziness" of photoshop, that aspect would be a sibling to the gaussian. photoshop's approach sounds like it's "piecewise linear", so something like `if dist <= range: return 1; if dist <= range + fuzziness: return 1 - (dist - range) / fuzziness; return 0` might do the trick

Comment: So i dont really care about the range since it is just basically how far from the target pixels it masks and i always want the whole picture, but for the fuzziness, im not sure how to implement the one you gave, it seems like its missing some code (There is a stray return 0, not sure but is that for the else statement of the second if?)

Comment: Also how do i know save this mask as a jpg? the process removes its layer (shape is now 256,256 instead of 256,256,3)

Comment: Im not sure if this is the correct method :  `result = cv2.normalize(greyedImage, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)` then save it the usual way `cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg',result)` . If i dont do the cv2.normalize i only get a black image when saving

Comment: "range" & fuzz doesn't mean spatial, it means "how similar is the color". -- the piece of code I gave in the previous comment is code for a piecewise linear function. you can simplify with `np.clip(1 - (dist-range)/fuzziness, 0.0, 1.0)` -- JPEG can't hold alpha channels. you can save the alpha channel as a grayscale jpeg but that's only nice to look at. or you can compose a 4-channel image as BGR + alpha, then save a PNG. -- the outputs of my code are scaled 0.0 to 1.0, so multiply by 255. it's still float, but imwrite casts to int. -- don't normalize(NORM_MINMAX), that does additional things.

Comment: i see, since i cant normalize the image, how do i count number of pixels at a given intensity. If this were a usual image , i would use `result=greyedImage.ravel()` followed by  `numPixels = np.count_nonzero((result>= 0)&(result<127))`. to count the number of grey pixels from completly black (0) to grey (127, 50% grey). But ravel does not work in this case and will return all pixels to be all black (0) .

Comment: to "count number of pixels at a given intensity", that's a histogram if you need to know for many intensities, or just the expression you gave, but with different thresholds (remember the value range). I don't know why you'd use ravel() for anything. it certainly has no effect.

Comment: Okay final question, how do you have a second target color (in photoshop its the eyedropper with the + icon) do you just run the function again but with a different target color (and possibly weights). How do i go about in combining both mask ?

Comment: what do you mean, second target color? in this answer, I have just one color. if you want to select a different color, change the constant in the code. you can derive that from any pixel or area of pixels in the source image. if you want masks for multiple colors, you can combine them however you like. averaging is okay, but so is per-element maximum or minimum.

Comment: Yes i would like to add a second color to be included in the mask, Wont averaging be bad, for example if my target is a red and blue color but on different position on the image wont they show  greyish? since on the first mask red would be a full white but on the blue mask the position of red will be full black? Can you please share how to do the per-element maximum/minimum, given 2 greyscale numpy image?

Comment: `np.maximum(mask1, mask2)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe applying quantization to your image might achieve the desired effect similar to color range as seen in Adobe Photoshop. Below is the code snippet that I've used for posterization, inspired by a solution on Stack Overflow ([Adobe Photoshop-style posterization and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064454/adobe-photoshop-style-posterization-and-opencv)). This approach utilizes quantization to reduce the number of colors, effectively targetting color on the image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray_scale = True
im = cv2.imread('6TODV.jpg')
# im = cv2.imread('2sb5L.jpg')
n = 4    # Number of levels of quantization

indices = np.arange(0,256)   # List of all colors 

divider = np.linspace(0,255,n+1)[1] # we get a divider

quantiz = np.int0(np.linspace(0,255,n)) # we get quantization colors

color_levels = np.clip(np.int0(indices/divider),0,n-1) # color levels 0,1,2..

palette = quantiz[color_levels] # Creating the palette

im2 = palette[im]  # Applying palette on image

im2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(im2) # Converting image back to uint8
if gray_scale:
    im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('quantized',im2)


# mouse callback function for picking color
def onClick(event,x,y,flags,param):
    """Called whenever user left clicks"""
    global pos_x, pos_y
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        print(f'click at {x},{y}')
        pos_x, pos_y = x, y

wname = "Original Image"
cv2.namedWindow(winname=wname)
cv2.setMouseCallback(wname, onClick)

pos_x, pos_y = 0, 0
while True:
    draw_im = im.copy()
    draw_im = cv2.circle(draw_im, (pos_x, pos_y), 2, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.imshow(wname,draw_im)

    if gray_scale:
        distances = np.abs(im2[pos_y, pos_x]-im2)
    else:
        distances = np.linalg.norm(im2[pos_y, pos_x]-im2, axis=2)
    distances = cv2.convertScaleAbs(distances)
    cv2.imshow('distances', distances)

    mask_threshold = 200 # set this to a value that works for you
    mask = distances < mask_threshold
    masked_im = im.copy()
    masked_im[~mask] = 255
    cv2.imshow('masked', masked_im)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This method should provide the effect you're looking for. Here are the results of the image processing applied to the provided picture.

N = 7

[image: n=7]

Gray Scale = True, N = 4
[image: n=4]
[image: n=4]

Comment: Sorry took so long to reply , I kind of like the your results there. I am unfamiliar with the method you are using. But it seems to have great result, So a question: what are the tune-able value here? It would seem that clicking on the, light - brown pixels would cause the mask to include blues pixels (which should not be masked since we only target brown), is there a value i can change to reduce the inclusions of blue pixel?

Answer (score 2):

So let me throw in an answer, it might not be a great answer but i did try to somehow go in that direction

My approach involves creating a mask for every hue value in a given hue range, after that the mask is then combined but with an assigned grey value depending on its position in the input range

```
image = cv2.imread('grade_0.jpg')

greyMask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) #create an empty numpy image with the same size as the input image, this will be our final mask

lowerHSV = -2
upperHSV = 20

HSVdifference = upperHSV - lowerHSV

if lowerHSV <= 0 : # account for 0
    HSVdifference = HSVdifference + 1

baseGreyValue = math.floor(255/HSVdifference)

#Create a mask for every hue value in our range and map it into a grey value

greyValue = baseGreyValue
for i in reversed(range(HSVdifference)): #loop through hue range in reverse order 

    if i > 0:
        Hvalue = i
    elif i <= 0:
        Hvalue = 180 - i

    mask = cv2.inRange(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV), np.array([Hvalue-1, 0, 0]), np.array([Hvalue, 255, 255])) # get all pixels at specific hue 
    indices = np.where(mask==255) #get all the index of pixels
    greyMask[indices[0], indices[1], :] = [greyValue, greyValue, greyValue] #assign grey tone to final mask
    greyValue = greyValue + baseGreyValue


cv2.imshow("grey mask", greyMask) 

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I apologize - my OpenCV is broken at the moment. But here is another method that I will implement in Imagemagick.

- Read the input
- Apply a sigmoidal contrast to emphasize the mid range and darken the lows and brighten the highs. (See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.adjust_sigmoid or just skip this step to have a linear equivalent)
- Apply a dark only threshold to contrast enhanced image (values below some threshold become black)

  Syntax: image[np.where((image<[T,T,T]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0] where T=some low threshold value
- Then apply a bright only threshold (values above some threshold become white)

  Syntax: image[np.where((image>[T,T,T]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0] where T=some high threshold value
- Then change all white values to black.

  Syntax: skip if using two np steps above
- Then convert to grayscale

  Syntax: image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

magick sample.jpg -sigmoidal-contrast 20,50% x.png

[image]

magick x.png -black-threshold 20% -white-threshold 80% -fill black -opaque white -colorspace gray result.png

[image]

The sigmoidal-contrast function is:

```
( 1/(1+exp(β*(α-u))) - 1/(1+exp(β*(α)) ) / ( 1/(1+exp(β*(α-1))) - 1/(1+exp(β*α)) )
```

and has a transfer curve (input to output) shape of:

[image]

Here is the linear equivalent process, which just skips the sigmoidal contrast. I change the threshold values to compensate some for the lack of the sigmoidal contrast. So it is just a low threshold followed by a high threshold followed by changing white to black, followed by convert to grayscale.

```
magick sample.jpg -black-threshold 30% -white-threshold 70% -fill black -opaque white -colorspace gray result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to hit the blue pixels also, i do not want to include the blue pixels

Comment: Use the two thresholds and use 3 different T values to threshold on the colors you want.